# How to UPDATE MySQL Rows with other values in the same column?

Tags: mysql, sql-update, match, rows

I have a table in MySQL that has some wrong data appearing as `0` in `col3` instead of the correct value.

The correct value for that `col3` column for those corrupt rows appear in other rows with the same `col1`, `col2`, and `col4` values where `col3` is not `0`.  (`col1` is the same value for all rows and just equals `US`.)

So to fix this, I just need to get all `col3` rows that equal `0` and set those `col3`'s to the value of the `col3` where `col3` does not equal `0` and where `col1 = 'US'` AND where `col2` and `col4` match.

Something like this:

```
UPDATE Table1 WHERE col1= 'US' AND col3 = '0' AND col2 = x AND col4 = y SET col3 = (SELECT col3 FROM Table1 WHERE col1= 'US' AND col2 = x AND col4 = y AND col3 != '0'
```

But how do I actually do that in MySQL as I just used `x` and `y` above as placeholders to explain the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a self join update:

```
UPDATE Table1 a
INNER JOIN Table1 b
    ON a.col2 = b.col2 AND
       a.col4 = b.col4 AND
       b.col3 <> 0
SET a.col3 = b.col3
WHERE
    a.col3 = 0 AND
    a.col1 = 'US'
```

Comment: How does your solution compare to Gordon Linoff's?

Comment: I think Gordon's query and mine should do the same thing, but he wrote his in such a way that the query is less ugly.  Test both, and if they both work then go with the one which you like the most.

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL, you would do this with a `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE Table1 t1 JOIN
       (SELECT t1.*
        FROM Table1 t1
        WHERE col3 <> 0 AND col1 = 'US'
       ) tt1
       ON tt1.col2 = t1.col2 AND tt1.col4 = t1.col4
   SET t1.col3 = tt1.col3
   WHERE t1.col3 = 0;
```

Comment: Can you please explain what this is doing?  For example, what are `x` and and `y` in this case?  (I was just using them as placeholders to explain the logic of what I wanted.)  Thank you.

Comment: @ProgrammerGirl . . . I misread the question.  They are `col2` and `col4`.